# Enumerating ordered tokens with all possible length in Perl

Tags: perl, token

Given this string:

```
<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>
```

What I want to do is to enumerate all possible ordered length like this:

```
<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>
<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0>
<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0>
<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM>
<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0>
<VACC-PROP-0>

<VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>
<NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>
<EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>
<MIR-0><PREP>
<PREP>
```

Not that the above is done by hand. It's possible that I may be missing something. 
But the idea is to identify all possible ordered tokens of all length (number of tokens).
I tried this code but failed, what's the best way to do it?

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $str = "<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>";

# Remove all the brackets
my @tokens = grep {!/^$/} split(/[><]/,$str);

# Print the combinations
foreach my $i (0 .. $#tokens) {

   print join(" ", @tokens[0..$i]),"\n";
}
```

Execute here: https://eval.in/51023

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want nested loops of arbitrarily depth.

```
for my $use_token0 (0..1) {
   for my $use_token1 (0..1) {
      for my $use_token2 (0..1) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

For that, you use [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aLoops)'s `NestedLoops`.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $str = "<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>";
my @tokens = split /(?<=>)(?=<)/, $str;

my $iter = NestedLoops([ ( [0,1] ) x @tokens ]);
while ( my @bools = $iter->() ) {
   say @tokens[ grep $bools[$_], 0..$#tokens ];
}
```

Although, in this case, you could simply use

```
my $str = "<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>";
my @tokens = split /(?<=>)(?=<)/, $str;

for my $i (0 .. (1<<@tokens)-1) {
   say @tokens[ grep $i & (1 << ($#tokens-$_)), 0..$#tokens ];
}
```

Comment: always a genius I knew from PM. Btw, given a string like 1234 (each digit represent a token), is there a way to enumerate in order but allowing missing token in between. e.g. 1234,123,12,13,14,23,24,34,234,etc..

Comment: I don't see an order in there

Comment: 13 is ordered in original string but not 31.

Comment: Both of the solution I gave preserve token order. Look at the what they print. It's always `@tokens[ 0..$#tokens ]` with some elements filtered out.

Comment: I just realized that! Thanks a million!

Comment: Btw, can explain the meaning of '1<<@tokens' and 'grep $i &'

Comment: You have N booleans. The second snippets represents them as N bits. That means `0..(1<<$N)-1` iterates through possible states of N bits. `$i & (1 << $j)` checks the state of bit j